A question about notation in Naive Set Theory
In chapter 4, introducing unions, Halmos offers three notations for the union of a collection of sets. The third notation, which he uses thereafter, looks like:
$$\bigcup_{X \in \mathfrak{C}}X$$
What is the last X for?

I don't really understand your question. This is just another notation for $\displaystyle{\bigcup\mathcal C}$. I suppose you could say that the "$X$" is there so that the notation is closely aligned to the notation for the union of an indexed family ${a_i}{i\in I}$ (cf. section 9), which is $\displaystyle{\bigcup{i\in I}a_i}$.

The baselines in the typesetting seem to have mislead me.

By way of analogy, consider the difference between the two expressions
$$
\sum_{k\in\{1,2,\ldots,C\}} k
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{k\in\{1,2,\ldots,C\}} f(k).
$$
Both of these have the same set of indices (the positive integers up to $C$) that they are summing over, but the quantity they are summing is different: the first expression literally adds the indices together, as in $1+2+\cdots+C$, while the second one adds together various numbers that are generated from the indices $k$ but are probably very different than them, resulting in $f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(C)$.
Similarly, we might consider the two expressions
$$
\bigcup_{X \in \mathfrak{C}}X
\quad\text{and}\quad
\bigcup_{X \in \mathfrak{C}} g(X).
$$
The first expression is indexed by the sets $X$ in $\mathfrak{C}$, and the sets we're asked to take the union of are those exact same sets $X$. But that wouldn't have to be the case: the second expression takes the union of various sets $g(X)$ that are generated from the index sets $X\in\mathfrak{C}$ but are probably very different than them.
So to answer the question directly: the $X$ in the subscript $X\in\mathfrak{C}$ names the index (dummy variable) used by the union notation, while the second $X$ tells us what we're actually taking the union of. Certainly a common use of this notation is to take the union of the index sets themselves, but that's only one of many possibilities.
